# Service Facade (As per Adam Bien) - EJB 3

Tags: service, ejb-3.0, java-ee-6, facade

I've read Adam Bien Rethinking Business tier.  It mentioned about creating a service facade, for example, OrderService.  However can you have many service facade for a large enterprise application.  I have Customer Module, Order Module, Transportation Module, can I create a service facade for each high level module instead of creating one big facade that includes all of these modules. So in my JSF 2.0 web app I can make a call like:
transportationServiceFacade.findDetails()
orderServiceFacade.findDetails()

instead of doing it this way

genericServiceFacade.findDetails()

I rather use many facades in my example.  Will this impact performance ?

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can. I don't know this specific book, but I know that Adam Bien a practicioner of simplicity and elegance. I think this is great, specially if you compare with the Enterprise Java solutions done in the EJB 2.x days. But the simplicity he adopts also comes, sometimes, with an oversimplification. As you could probably realize, as your system grows, it makes more sense to split a generic facade into other facades, more specialized.

This certainly doesn't impacts performance, as these EJBs will also be polled. If anything, you'd be consuming a bit more memory, but I wouldn't worry about this, as it's usually better to care about your architecture first, then with performance. Even then, performance shouldn't a thing of "I think", but "I know" (ie: measure, and prove to yourself that something is really impacting the performance).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Will consider doing it multiple facades.

Answer (score 0):

ServiceFacase is only a pattern and you may modify it as suites your needs. However, the idea of ServiceFacade pattern is to group boundary methods of a single component into one single class - service facade. If you have a need for more separate service facades, chances are you also have a need for more decoupled components. 

Another suggestion is that if you call methods of two different facades from single action on frontend, it is better to group that business logic into a single method in one of the facades. Service facade should always start transaction and it is better to reduce the number of transactions in one action, ideally to a single transaction. Service facade should be designed for the needs of a client accessing a component from outside rather than by anything else.

Answer (score 0):

As per Adam's Bien "Real World Java EE Patterns. Rethinking Best Practices" (2012), Service Facade, or Control, is optional decomposition of complex service layer, when Boundaries become bloated and in-cohesive.

Nowadays we can suffer from overcomplicated logic at web tier (Resource, Controller, REST API front tier) which could consist of combining results from multiple services. Those would be good candidate for refactoring in terms of Control (Service Facade) pattern, which will improve maintainability and follow separation of concerns. You will also get easiness of testing for free.